# Prestashop - how to write parent category on breadcrumbs

Tags: smarty, prestashop, breadcrumbs

I am making my own breadcrumbs on prestashop in category.tpl. I have 2 depth menu. In subcategory page I want to add upper category name and link to it in my breadcrumbs.

For example I have menu 
-fruits
---apple
---banana
-vegetables 
-bread
 ---roll
 ---bread

when I am on apple page I want to have breadcrumbs like this : "home < fruits < apple". I have problem with dinamical write "fruits" and link to it.

Sorry for my english. Hope for yours answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent category using id_parent property:

```
$category->id_parent
```

You can also check level depth of current category to know when display parent category or not:

```
{if $category->level_depth > some_int_value}
    {* display parent breadcrumb *}
{/if}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I know that i can get parent category id, but i want to have link and name of parent category.

Comment: The simpliest way is in front CategoryController set parent_category as a param to smarty. Then you can have access in TPL to category name and link just like normal category do. For link you must use $link->getCategoryLink(...) in category.tpl

Comment: Please, help me with set it in Controller and with use it in category.tpl. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I recommend you that you hire some developer for this. You can crash your shop if you don't know how to do this, even with a detailed tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: I would like this detailed tutorial very much, please if it is not a problem. I am working on copy so it is no dangerous for my shop.

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly answer for the origin question, but it can help someone who wants to make some changes in category breadcrumbs

presta 1.7 - if you want to add **root category** to breadcrumbs

original path: Home > Category > Sub Category 1 > ...

Home > **Root Category** > Category > Sub Category 1 > ...

controllers/front/listingCategoryController.php

```
public function getBreadcrumbLinks()
{
    $breadcrumb = parent::getBreadcrumbLinks();
    // adding root category to breadcrumbs
    $rootCategory = Category::getRootCategory();
    $breadcrumb['links'][] = array(
        'title' => $rootCategory->name,
        'url'   => $this->context->link->getCategoryLink($rootCategory->id, $rootCategory->link_rewrite),
    );
    //

    foreach ($this->category->getAllParents() as $category) {
        if ($category->id_parent != 0 && ! $category->is_root_category) {
            $breadcrumb['links'][] = $this->getCategoryPath($category);
        }
    }

    $breadcrumb['links'][] = $this->getCategoryPath($this->category);

    return $breadcrumb;
}
```

Comment: How about an explanation?
Code should be highlighted with the code tool.

Comment: In code sample above, breadcrumb is called twice because of `parent::`, you'll probably replace it by `$breadcrumb = ProductListingFrontController::getBreadcrumbLinks();`